# How to Configure IIS Express for mp4 videos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written an application using C# ASP.Net MVC which in its Home View lists all folders of a Directory in a table. Each `tr` has a single `td` and `td` contains `a`. Clicking on `a` (folder name) replaces a `div` of Home View with a partial view which in turn lists all mp4 videos along with duration of that folder in similar way and I have used `jQuery AJAX` for such replacement. By clicking on VideoName video gets played and I have used `video` tag and specified  `type="video/mp4"`.

I have added a Website in IIS Server where hostname is tutorials.com, physical path is App path and in binding  I have used 192.168.1.3 : 80. In DNS Server I have created a Primary Zone named tutorials.com and in a record used the same IP. I can watch video tutorials from any PC of my local network without any issue.

If I open the application in Visual Studio and press `F5` or `Ctrl+F5` it starts using IIS Express and when I click on Videoname some videos are rendered properly and some do not. How to configure IIS Express to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think it's iis configuraion, it's the web page.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to set the MIME type as IIS Express by default doesn’t have the MIME Type to play video.

Comment: @Dani I think you are right. What is the problem  of the web page?

Answer (score 2):

Add Following XML Code in the WebConfig.xml file.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogv" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

The Above Lines allow the MIME Types.

Comment: I have two config one with Capital W in App root and another with small w in Views folder. I have tried by adding it in both under `<system.webServer>` in all possible combination and it does not solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Before configuring the mappings, you have to remove the existing ones too. I use a configuration like this in my `web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".ogv"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".m4v"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/>
    <remove fileExtension=".webm"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: haha bingo! I believe this should solve the issue. Great man :)

Comment: no @AshishSrivastava it does not solve the problem either! It might be a solution for the case where none works in IIS Express but in IIS Server.

Comment: I üsse it for production for its server for years. You might have a different problem then.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Dani thought right at first and I agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue- some MP4 clips work and some not.
Server is IIS Express on Windows 10.
Tested different clients.
The clips can be saved from all clients- no issues.
On other server (Apache) the clips work fine.
Although the clips appear not to be working, they actually do (at least on some systems). But they are not streamed (fragments/ranges are not treated as separate). They have to be completely transferred and than they start to play.
Chrome on small ARM Linux- they simply do not work.
Chrome or Edge on Intel Win 10- they are transferred and than they play. For bigger clips it might take a while.
On Apache the same clips (with issues on IIS) work fine no matter the client.
So in my opinion there are several options- change server, change client or save the clips and than watch them.
Another option might be to change the clips. Have not played with this one, but changing key frames and frame rate might also help in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your `IIS Express` directory in prompt and do this `appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.mp4',mimeType='vieo/mp4']`

As suggested by Dani, if the problem is with the web page than I hope you should add `<meta http-equiv-"X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` to the `<head>` block of a webpage for testing as mentioned in [How to use HTML5 to play video files on your webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924821(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It says ....................... cannot add duplicate collection entry ............................

Comment: That was the answer for your question - `How to configure IIS Express to solve the problem?` Hold on I'm trying with the rest!

Comment: Did you check your `Web` tab in the project properties?

Comment: under Start Action -> Current Page is selected; Servers -> IIS Express; Debuggers -> ASP.NET